# Whether this linear transformation can be diagonalizable or not

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, diagonalization

> Let $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $A$ has $n$ eigenvalues: $1,2,...,n$, and $B$ also has $n$ eigenvalues: $\sqrt{p_1},\sqrt{p_2},...,\sqrt{p_n}$, in which $p_i$ denotes the $i$-th prime. The question is whether the linear transformation $T\in\operatorname{End}(M_n(\mathbb{C})): X\to AXB$ can be diagonalizable or not.

And in general, if $A$ has $n$ eigenvalues $\{\lambda_i\}_{i=1}^n$, and $B$ has $n$ eigenvalues $\{\mu_i\}_{i=1}^n$, under what restrictions of the eigenvalues we can claim the linear transformation can be diagonalizable?

Now I have a conclusion that: if both of $A,B$ can be diagonalizable, then $T$ above can be diagonalizable, so I wonder if the converse still holds? I.e. if $T$ is diagonalizable, then both of  $A,B$ can be diagonalizable, or weaker: one of the $A,B$ can be diagonalizable and $T$ can be diagonalizable, so is the other?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You are talking about $A\otimes B$. I think it's easier to generalise and let $A,B$ be different square dimensions. Then by induction you can assume that $A,B$ each consist of a single Jordan block. I think it's clear if either has eigenvalue $0$, so the difficult case is when both eigenvalues are non-zero [and indeed we can assume both are $1$ (irrelevant)] . Now the result would follow from the result in this question, but as we're just trying to show the whole thing doesn't reduce to a load of $1\times 1$ blocks it should be easier. Ctd

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2718267/jordan-block-of-kronecker-product?rq=1

Comment: @ancientmathematician What do you mean by "it's clear if either has eigenvalue $0$"? What is clear and why? I'd say that even the result for $A = B$ (where $A$ and $B$ are a Jordan block associated with $0$) [is surprising](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3300053/81360).

Comment: @BenGrossmann I think the full description is surprising, but I thought it was clear that the tensor product of two non-$0$ $0$-Jordan blocks isn't $0$, so we don't have diagonalisability in that case. I wish this question had been answered fully: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2736208/how-to-find-the-jordan-canonical-form-of-tensor-products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume $A\not=O$, $B\not=O$: if either is $O$ then $T=O$ is diagonalisable.

Let $V$ be the $n$-dimensional space. Then we are looking at the map $T=A\otimes B: V\otimes V\to V\otimes V$. Suppose that $T$ is diagonalisable. We prove that both $A$ and $B$ are diagonalisable.

We can decompose $V=\bigoplus U_i$ and $V=\bigoplus W_j$ corresponding to the Jordan-blocks of $A$ and $B$. Then $V\otimes V$ is decomposed into the following $T$-invariant subspaces, $V\otimes V=\bigoplus U_i\otimes W_j$. As $T$ is diagonalisable, it acts on a given $U_i\otimes W_j$ as multiplication by $\lambda_i\mu_j$ where $\lambda_i, \mu_j$ are the eigenvalues of $A,B$ on $U_i, W_j$.

Suppose for a contradiction that some $U_r$ has dimension at least $2$, and has basis $e_1,e_2,\dots$; and that $W_s$ has basis $f_1,\dots$. Then $T:e_2\otimes f_1\mapsto (e_1+\lambda_r e_2)\otimes \mu_s f_1$. This is not multiplication by $\lambda_r\mu_s$ unless $\mu_s=0$. So we are done unless all the $\mu_j=0$.

As $B\not=O$ not all its Jordan blocks are of dimension $1$, so we may swap $A$ and $B$ in the above and again we will be done unless all the $\lambda_i=0$.

Now $A\not=O, B\not=0$ so each has a block of size at least $2$, say $U_1$ with basis $e_1,e_2,\dots$ and $W_1$ with basis $f_1,f_2,\dots$. Then $T:e_2\otimes f_2\mapsto e_1\otimes f_1$, and so $T$ is not multiplication by $0$ after all, and we are done.